# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied, despite running the code as an administrator

Tags: python, fft

I am somewhat new to python.

I am trying to implement a 2d FFT to convert a whole folder of image:

```
import cv2 
import os 
import glob 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
def calculate_2dft(input):
    ft = np.fft.ifftshift(input)
    ft = np.fft.fft2(ft)
    return np.fft.fftshift(ft)
img_dir = os.path.abspath(r"folder (diectory of all images) path")
data_path = os.path.join(img_dir,'*g') 
files = glob.glob(data_path) 
data = [] 
for f1 in files: 
    img = cv2.imread(f1) 
    data.append(img)
image = plt.imread(img_dir)
```

I get:

```
          1 # Read and process image
    ----> 2 image = plt.imread(img_dir)

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Comment: I don't think you can pass a folder to `plt.imread()`. I think you need to loop over each file and pass that to the `plt.imread()`.

Comment: I think, first think to do is run as administrator to check out if the problem is this. If still continue check folder permissions

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Nick ODell - how do I avoid this doing manually? I have a large database (700+ images)

Comment: Why not doing the same thing as you are doing to load images with `cv2.imread` in a `for` loop?